# PHP session variable trying to set it to users id from SQL database upon login

Tags: php, html, sql

I am trying to set the session id for a user to their corresponding id from a database. The ID of a user is a simple auto increment INT in the SQL database. The user logs in with their email and password. Once the session is started, I want a session variable to store that users ID. My code for the login php file to create the session id at the moment is as follows.

```
$_SESSION['user_id'] =  $user_id;
```

My code to set the session user id to a variable in another php file is then as follows:

```
$user_of_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
```

When I try insert $user_of_id into another table of the database in the php script I've declared it in, it does not work. I have session_start(); in all necessary php files. I am hoping someone can point out my mistake.

The full code is as follows for the user login php:

```
<?php
 session_start();

$db =mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "project_website1");

if(isset($_POST['Login_Btn']))  {


    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    $password = md5($password);// Decrypt hash of password stored in database

    $mySQLQuery = "SELECT * FROM userdetails WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'";
    $resultOfQuery = mysqli_query($db, $mySQLQuery);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($resultOfQuery) == 1) {

        $_SESSION['user_id'] =  $user_id;
        header("location: User_Home_Page.html");
    }else{          
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Login Fail";

    }




}
 ?>
```

The php for uploading my document is as follows:

```
<?php
session_start();
$db =mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "project_website1");
if(isset($_POST['upload_btn'])){

    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $taskTitle = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tasktitle']);
    $taskDescription = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['TaskDescription']);
    $numPages = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['number_of_pages']);

    $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['file_document']['name'];
    $file_loc = $_FILES['file_document']['tmp_name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['file_document']['size'];
    $file_type = $_FILES['file_document']['type'];
    $folder="uploads/";

    move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$file);

    $numWords = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['number_of_words']);
    $deadlineClaim = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['deadline_claim']);
    $deadlineComplete = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['deadline_complete']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO task(user_id, title, description, file, file_type, file_size, pg_num, num_words, deadline_claim, deadline_completion) VALUES( '$user_id', '$taskTitle', '$taskDescription', '$file', '$file_type', '$file_size', '$numPages', '$numWords', '$deadlineClaim', '$deadlineComplete')";
    mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    header("location: User_Home_Page.html");

}

?>
```

Comment: Did you check the value of `$user_of_id` before inserting?

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Do you have some errors?

Comment: why would the user_Id be a number rather than the email address or a username? find it odd... typically you store the sessionID alongside the userID

Comment: I receive no errors, I am trying to upload a file to one of the tables in the database with the current logged in users id. For some reason the form sends with no errors but it does not enter the database. I have tested my code and it is something to do with the session id of the user. I have also checked my SQL query and it is fine.

Comment: there isn't enough code to support this question

Comment: I will provide the two php files

Comment: I have updated my post to provide the full php code

Comment: "it is something to do with the session id of the user" how do you know this? You're really not providing enough information to be helpful.

Comment: If I simply pass an INT in my VALUES statement instead of $user_id for the user_id column of the database it works perfectly.

Comment: Hi Ryan. So I have to perform an SQL query to retrieve  that specific users id from the database and store it in the global session variable before I can use the global session variable in another php script?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Question has been updated after my answer with a full code. Perhaps this answer needs a rework.

If you are using `session_start();` correctly (at the begining of your document), your code is fine.

*file1.php* should be:

```
<?php    
session_start();
$user_id = 5;
$_SESSION['user_id'] =  $user_id;
```

*file2.php* should be:

```
<?php    
session_start();
$user_of_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
echo 'User-ID: '.$user_of_id; //User-ID: 5
```

If you can't output the user id, try to debug your code by checking if your session is set (`print_r($_SESSION);`). Perhaps you have got an if-clause which will not be executed or something like this (`if(false) $_SESSION['user_id'] =  $user_id;` would be wrong).

If you can't output the user id anyway, you have got a problem with your server (try using this minimal code) or your client (try using antoher browser / computer).